# AWS EC2 not installing nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html), but it appears that nodejs isn't being installed.

The output I get is:

> sudo yum install nodejs
>
> Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
>
> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
>
> No package nodejs available.
>
> Error: Nothing to do

I've checked around online, but can't find a way forward. How do I install nodejs on ubuntu in aws ec2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you started with a new instance and did not update it with latest updates or package sources first. You are missing the source for NodeJS packages.

This will add the source and install nodejs:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Follow this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Answer (score 0):

You can install the nvm

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash
```

Then run the command

```
source ~/.profile
```

Now run this and this will show will all installed or other versions of packages:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

Installed packages will be in green. Install whatever version you want:

```
nvm install 6.0.0
```

Check where is not installed:

```
which node
```

Check current version:

```
node -v
```